# AWS sdk can't be referred in angular-cli project

Tags: angular, aws-sdk, angular-cli

I tried to use aws sdk and got this typescript build error in a brand new angular2 cli project after following the official aws-sdk link (https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk)

```
ERROR in ./src/app/service/aws.service.ts
Module build failed: Error: /Users/slin/pan/protego/crossbow/src/app/service/aws.service.ts (26,13): Argument of type '{ region: string; accessKeyId: string; secretAccessKey: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConfigurationOptions & ConfigurationServicePlaceholders & APIVersions'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'accessKeyId' does not exist in type 'ConfigurationOptions & ConfigurationServicePlaceholders & APIVersions'.)
    at _checkDiagnostics (/Users/slin/pan/protego/crossbow/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:116:15)
    at /Users/slin/pan/protego/crossbow/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:141:17
    at tryCatch (/Users/slin/pan/protego/crossbow/node_modules/es6-promise/dist/es6-promise.js:410:12)
    at invokeCallback (/Users/slin/pan/protego/crossbow/node_modules/es6-promise/dist/es6-promise.js:425:13)
    at publish (/Users/slin/pan/protego/crossbow/node_modules/es6-promise/dist/es6-promise.js:393:7)
    at flush (/Users/slin/pan/protego/crossbow/node_modules/es6-promise/dist/es6-promise.js:121:5)
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:415:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:344:13)
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts 17:0-51
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi main
```

My code is just simple as this:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';

@Injectable()
export class AwsService {
    loggedin: boolean;
    aws_accessKeyId: string;
    aws_secretAccessKey: string;
    aws_region: string;

    constructor() {
        this.loggedin = false;
        this.aws_region = 'us-west-2';
    }

    login(
    ) {
        AWS.config.update({
            region: this.aws_region,
            accessKeyId: this.aws_accessKeyId,
            secretAccessKey: this.aws_secretAccessKey
        });
        this.loggedin = true;
        console.log(this.aws_accessKeyId, this.aws_secretAccessKey);
    }
}
```

Is the aws-sdk truly working for typescript? Or did I miss some setting for angular2-cli project? Could this an issue aws-sdk not support es6?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found my problem. It works actually just following the angular-cli instruction. My problem is aws latest API has been changed, but they didn't update their api document yet.

The ^2.7.11 syntax should be:

```
    AWS.config.update({
        region: this.aws_region,
        credentials: {
            accessKeyId: this.aws_accessKeyId,
            secretAccessKey: this.aws_secretAccessKey
        }
    });
```